# Can't Install Imagescanner on Python 2.7 : PIL package incompatible

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, spyder, image-scanner

I'm a newbie trying to install imagescanner-0.9-py2.6 in Spyder 2.7.6 running on Linux Peppermint 6, and am having problems installing the dependencies for PIL.

`easy_install imagescanner-0.9-py2.6.egg` fails with message:

```
"Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PIL')
```

I've tried to install PIL using Synaptic Package Manager and also using  command lines :
`easy_install python image library`, `easy_install pillow`, `easy_install image`, `pip install image`, and `pip install pillow -U`

But I still get the same error.

`pip install PIL` gives the error:

```
"No matching distribution found for PIL"
```

(I think) I've completely uninstalled PIL after each failed attempt.

From reading other postings it seems that there has been a similar problem with installing PIL for the last 6 years or so, and various workarounds have been proposed, but none of them seem simple or applicable to my situation. Maybe a more recent fix has subsequently become available but if so, I've been unable to find details of this.

As a newbie, what is the simplest way for me to get up and running with imagescanner in Python 2.7.6?

If there's no simple fix, would changing Spyder to a different Python distribution help resolve this problem; or is there some newer app which performs the same function as imagescanner which I could use instead to control and import images from a scanner using Python?